# How to bring AngularJS app and Flask on same domain?

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I have created a web application in AngularJS and a Flask server up and running on `localhost:5000/`. I wanted to make a login service, so I included the following code in my controller in AngularJS:

```
$scope.login = function() {
            $http({
              method: 'POST',
              data: {
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
              },
              url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log('successCallback')
              }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log('errorCallback')
              });
}
```

I call the `login()` method from the UI. But this gives me the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Further when I researched on this error, I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource), which states that my page is on a different domain than my server. How do I bring my AngularJS and python server on same domain? What piece of code will I have to specify so that in place of `url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/'`, I just have to specify `'/login'`? I know this might be trivial question, but please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your app from `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` rather than `http://localhost:5000/`? While they both lead to the same location, from the browser's perspective they're separate domains.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both, same output in browser when I open the links, and same error in making the post call through Angular $http method

Answer (score 0):

Change app.run in flask code and your url all to 127.0.0.1 and then browse 127.0.0.1, then it will work.